# In C, does casting a pointer have overhead?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, dynamic, casting

I have some code here that looks horrendous, and thinking to myself I will never have to see it nor debug it again (it will be hidden by a completely different programming language), does it have overhead to cast in this fashion?

```
void SubtractFloat (void *in, void *out){

    int* a = (int*)in;
    int* b = a++;

    float c = * (float*)a;
    float d = * (float*)b;

    float* e = (float*)out;

    *e = c - d;
}
```

(yes i understand the unbelievable code violations, but its necessary to forward the type responsibility upwards)

*on a side note, could this be made cleaner? (I'll even take assembler suggestions)

Comment: in theory, if all type casting was perfectly correct (that is, it was checked ahead of time) is it necessary to use a memcpy?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “checked.” Checked alignment? Checked that the compiler supports this? Even if the alignment is good, the C standard permits a compiler to transform aliasing violations into any other behavior. Checking the alignment will not fix that. `memcpy` expresses the proper semantics to the compiler, so it is a good solution to use. In C, unions may also be used, but they are not necessary here.

Comment: Is the code intended to subtract the first element pointed to by `in` from the second? Although `a` is initially given the value of `in`, it is then incremented while initializing `b`. And `b` receives the value of `a` before the increment. Thus `b` ends up pointing to `in` while `a` points further on. That is a strange way to write that code.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `a` and `b` instead of just taking `c` and `d` directly from `in`? The code relies in int and float having the same size already.

Comment: Eric Postpischil corrected it as the first cast really makes no sense, it was the only way i could get rid of the warnings and do var++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most modern C implementations, converting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type has zero or negligible performance cost. A bigger concern would be moving data between general-purpose registers and floating-point registers.

As you note, the code in your question has violations of C’s strict aliasing rules, although your C implementation may support it. Nonetheless, two alternatives are:

If the circumstances of `in`, `out`, and your C implementation support accessing the contents as `float`, then use:

```
float *fin = in, *fout = out;
fout[0] = fin[1] - fin[0];
```

If accessing the data as `float` is not supported, then use:

```
char *p = in;
float c, d, e;
memcpy(&d, p, sizeof d);
memcpy(&c, p + sizeof d, sizeof c);
e = c - d;
memcpy(out, &e, sizeof e);
```

Note that although `memcpy` is nominally worse in the C abstract machine (it copies bytes one by one), a good C implementation will optimize this code. (If alignment of `in` and `out` is not a problem, then, for typical processors, a good compiler should generate two loads, a subtract, and a store. If alignment is a consideration, some form of unaligned loads and stores may be needed. But they would be needed in any case.)

Comment: Actually, it would be `fin[1] - fin[0]`, if equivalent to code in question - not sure, though, if this really was intended by TO...

Comment: that looks incredibly clean, I have never tried using array syntax for pointers. its also useful to keep alignment in mind as the data has to be allocated AND manipulated in float registers... never thought of that. it means worst case the compiler forces data between registers...

Comment: @EricPostpischil `a = in, b = a++, c = a (== in[1]), d = b (== in[0])`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Ah, nice catch. I wonder if that was intentional in the original code.

Comment: ah yes, i noticed when i ran a unit test that the answer went from -5 to 5, it doesn't matter too much as long as there is a standard

Comment: I don't see any strict aliasing violation, can you elaborate?  Suppose the call site is `_Static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), "foo"); float a[2] = { 0 }, b; SubtractFloat(a, &b);`

Comment: Its simply that there "could be" a domain of failure given extenuating circumstances. if something isn't catching this code it could result in "unexpected behavior".

Comment: @M.M: The problem is we do not have the provenance of `in` and `out`, and passing them as `void *` is suspect. I should not say there are violations of the aliasing rules but rather that there may be, in general, so we need to code defensively.

Comment: There could be a violation if the caller passes the wrong arguments, but that's true of just about any function that takes pointers.

Comment: @M.M: If we are passed `float *`, it is reasonable to assume we will find `float` objects there unless stated otherwise, and, when we are passed `void *`, it is reasonable to guard against something funny going on.

Comment: @M.M: when using 'void' we must handle the exceptions it will generate elsewhere, to affirm a predictable program flow. whether that be from a framework or another function calling it. responsibility falls in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)"Axiom of choice"