# Do modern c++ compilers optimize assignments after type casting?

Tags: c++, optimization, strict-aliasing

Take the following code:

```
char chars[4] = {0x5B, 0x5B, 0x5B, 0x5B};
int* b = (int*) &chars[0];
```

The `(int*) &chars[0]` value is going to be used in a loop (a long loop). Is there any advantage in using `(int*) &chars[0]` over `b` in my code? Is there any overhead in creating `b`? Since I only want to use it as an alias and improve code readability.

Also, is it OK to do this kind of type casting as long as I know what I'm doing? Or should I always `memcpy()` to another array with the correct type and use that? Would I encounter any kind of undefined behavior? because in my testing so far, it works, but I've seen people discouraging this kind of type casting.

Comment: You might find https://godbolt.org/ useful

Comment: Modern compilers optimize practically everything you can think of.  A temporary variable will certainly be optimized away if that helps.  Conversely, an expression used several times is very likely to be computed once and cached in a register, as if you had assigned it to a temporary variable (common subexpression elimination).  So you will probably get the same code either way you write it; hence just choose whatever is clearer.

Comment: There are no assignments in your code.  Only initialisations  (the `=`s are not assignment).  In any event, simple typecasting to initialise variables, as in your example, are no-cost operations when you get down to the level of machine instructions. In your case, the compiler can recognize that `&chars[0]` is a valid memory address, and typically will just initialise `b` with the same value (type matters to the compiler, not so much to machine instructions).  Subsequent code that uses those variables may have undefined behaviour. [Also, testing cannot prove *absence* of undefined behaviour].

Comment: @NateEldredge If I understood correctly, the value would have to be registered anyway and hence it doesn't matter, right?. Thanks for the comments everyone. Would be nice if you posted it as an answer.

Comment: Btw, in this example, why would you even bother with casting from the array?  `int x = 0x5b5b5b5b; int *b = &x;` is shorter, avoids strict aliasing problems, and with this value is even endian-independent.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand about whether the cast has a strict aliasing problem, but if it did then `memcpy` would fix it, and a decent compiler can optimize out the memcpy as well, so it would have no extra cost.  In C++20 there is probably a way to do it with `bit_cast` instead.

Comment: And even without alias issue, there is endianess issue (not with that specific value though)...

Comment: AFAIK, a C compiler does not insert any code when casting a pointer - which means that both `chars` and `b` are just memory addresses. See this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658664/in-c-does-casting-a-pointer-have-overhead

Comment: What if `sizeof(int) > 4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it OK to do this kind of type casting as long as I know what I'm doing?

No, this is not OK. **This is not safe**. The C++ standard does not allow that. You can access to an object representation (ie. casting an object pointer to `char*`) although the result is dependent of the target platform (due to the *endianess* and padding). However, *you cannot do the opposite safely* (ie. without an undefined behaviour).

More specifically, the `int` type can have **different alignment requirements** (typically aligned to 4 or 8 bytes) than `char` (not aligned). Thus, your array is likely not aligned and the cast cause an undefined behaviour when `b` will be dereferenced. Note that it can cause a crash on some processors (AFAIK, POWER for example) although mainstream x86-64 processors supports that. Moreover, compilers can assume that `b` is aligned in memory (ot `alignof(int)`).

> Or should I always memcpy() to another array with the correct type and use that?

Yes, or alternative C++ operations like the new [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) available since C++20. Do not worry about performance: most compilers (GCC, Clang, ICC, and certainly MSVC) does optimize such operations (called *type punning*).

> Would I encounter any kind of undefined behavior?

As said before, yes, as long as the type punning is not done correctly. For more information about this you can read the following links:

- [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)
- [reinterpret_cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)
- [Objects and alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object)

> because in my testing so far, it works, but I've seen people discouraging this kind of type casting.

It often works on simple examples on x86-64 processors. However, when you are dealing with a big code, compilers does perform silly optimizations (but totally correct ones regarding the C++ standard). To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): "Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behaviour (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.". Such issue are very hard to debug as they generally only appear when optimizations are enabled and in some specific cases. The result of a program can change regarding the inlining of functions which is dependent of compiler heuristics. In your case, this is dependent of the alignment of the stack which is dependent of compiler optimizations and declared/used variables in the current scope. Some processors does not support unaligned accesses (eg. accesses that cross a cache line boundary) which resulting in an hardware exception of data corruption.

So put it shortly, "it works" so far does not means it will always work everywhere anytime.

> The (int*) &chars[0] value is going to be used in a loop (a long loop). Is there any advantage in using (int*) &chars[0] over b in my code? Is there any overhead in creating b? Since I only want to use it as an alias and improve code readability.

Assuming you use a correct way to do type punning (eg. `memcpy`), then optimizing compilers can fully optimize this initialization as long as optimization flags are enabled. You should not worry about that unless you find that the generated code is poorly optimized. **Correctness matters more than performance**.

Comment: Thankfully, there is no alignment requirement in C++ - or otherwise many C APIs wouldn't be callable from C++

Comment: @mmomtchev Did you read the links in the answer? cppreference [explicitly state this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment). This is also mainly why compilers add padding in struct (besides performance improvements). For more information, please read the Section 6.6.5 of the C++17 standard. For example, it explicitly states: "*An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type*".

Comment: C++ compilers align when they allocate the storage - and even this is implementation dependent. But  when they are accessing it, they support both aligned and unaligned data. Otherwise C++ won't be binary compatible with anything else.

Comment: @mmomtchev I checked more carefully and the same thing also applies in C so the binary compatibility argument is not relevant here. [This](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types) page explain this more precisely. The C11 (§6.3.2.3) standard is very clear about this: "*If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.*". So put it shortly: this is an *undefined behaviour* to do that in *both C and C++*.

Comment: It seems that this was added to C11 because of architectures which cannot load/store unaligned words at all - ARM being the typical example. ARM compilers have a `__packed` pointer attribute which generates two or more separate loads in these cases - but this was not specified in C11 and it is still a non-standard feature. As C11 remains backwards compatible, unaligned memory access still works on architectures on which it worked before. This way of accessing data is very common in TCP/IP networking code and it is used in the `ntohs`/`ntohl` functions on x86. It does not work on ARM.

Comment: @mmomtchev: Architectures which cannot handle unaligned loads at all substantially predate the C89 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, a C compiler does not insert any code when casting a pointer - which means that both `chars` and `b` are just memory addresses. Normally a C++ compiler should compile this in the same way as a C compiler - this the reason C++ has different, more advanced, casting semantics.

But you can always compile this and then disassemble it in `gdb` to see for yourself.

Otherwise, as long as you are aware of the endianness problems or potentially different `int` sizes on exotic platforms, your casting is safe.

See this question also: [In C, does casting a pointer have overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658664/in-c-does-casting-a-pointer-have-overhead)

Comment: The casting is not safe even if `sizeof(int)` would be 4, typically due to different alignment constraints (nothing prevent `chars` to be miss-aligned). And even if so, AFAIK this would be unsafe regarding the C++ specification.

Comment: Reading unaligned words, even if it is not the fastest solution performance-wise, still works.

Comment: @mmomtchev: It works on all modern desktop machines.  There are many embedded platforms and a few "vintage" desktop machines such as the 68000-based Macintosh where it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

If code performs multiple discrete byte operations using a pointer derived from a pointer to a type which requires word alignment, clang will sometimes replace the discrete writes with a word write that would succeed if the original object was aligned for that word type, but would fail on systems that don't support unaligned accesses if the object isn't aligned the way the compiler expects.

Among other things, this means that if one casts a pointer to T into a pointer to a union containing T, code which attempts to use the union pointer to access the original type may fail if the union contains any types that require an alignment stricter than the original type, *even if the union is only accessed via the member of the original type*.